# Why is my memoization decorator not working for the Ackermann function?

Tags: python, recursion, decorator, memoization, traceback

I wrote a decorator that can memoize functions, here's how it looks like:

```py
def memoizator(func):
    cache = {}

    def wrapper(*args):
        if args not in cache:
            cache[args] = func(*args)
        return cache[args]
    
    return wrapper
```

I tested it on the Fibonacci function:

```py
@memoizator
def fibo(n):
    if n < 2:
        return n
    return fibo(n-1) + fibo(n-2)
```

And it worked perfectly. However when I tried doing the same with the Ackermann function:

```py
@memoizator
def ackermann(m, n):
    if m == 0:
        return n + 1
    elif n == 0:
        return ackermann(m - 1, 1)
    else:
        return ackermann(m - 1, ackermann(m, n - 1))
```

I only were able to compute `ackermann(3 ,4)`, anything above that would result in an avalanche of tracebacks and recursion errors. The error messages were what you can see below but copy pasted like 100 times.

```
  File "c:\path\memoize.py", line 54, in ackermann
    return ackermann(m - 1, ackermann(m, n - 1))
                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\path\memoize.py", line 8, in wrapper
    cache[args] = func(*args)
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

I can tell that this is a recursion problem and that my memoizator just can't deal with this beast. But why? Is there a way to write a more general decorator which could also deal with this or would I have to write specialized ones for more complicated recursive functions? And what's up with the tracebacks/error messages, why do I get 100 copies of the same thing?

Comment: The outer recursive call to `ackerman` doesn't strictly shrink over time, as it's second argument is the *result* of a recursive call, not just a decremented version of `m` or `n`. Basically your recursion tree blows up, because each level of recursion includes its own possibly large stack of recursive calls. (Add `print(m, n))` to the beginning of `ackerman` to see the progression of the arguments.)

Comment: Wikipedia has an iterative implementation of the Ackermann function: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ackermann_function#Computation That would let you avoid the recursion depth error.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I can now see why computing it using recursion is such a big problem even with memoization. However I'm still confused by the spam of tracebacks and error messages in the console. It's the 1st time ever something like this has happened to me.

Comment: I'd just like to point out that this exists https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.cache

Comment: Memorization does not solve revision depth issues. Your `fibo` function would also fail with recursion depth exceeded if you called it with a big enough `n`. And Python has a revision depth limit, which is best counters by not using recursive algorithms. Any recursive algorithm can be rewritten without recursion.

Answer (score 2):

We can implement this as a singly recursive function, rather than your doubly recursive one:

```
def ackermann(m, n):
    while m > 0:
        if n == 0:
            n = 1
        else:
            n = ackermann(m, n - 1)

        m -= 1

    return n + 1
```

But we're going to run into the same stack issues.  We can expand the stack using `sys.setrecursionlimit()`, but we likely can't expand it enough to solve the problem (I couldn't expand much beyond 1K -> 30K frames.)

As @NickODell suggests (+1), we can try a non-recursive approach that Wikipedia outlines.  What the following does is substitute an *explicit* stack (a `list`) for an *implicit* stack (the call stack.)  The `list` stack can grow orders of magnitude greater in size than the call stack before Python blows up:

```
def ackermann(m, n):
    stack = [m, n]

    while len(stack) > 1:
        n = stack.pop()

        if (m := stack.pop()) == 0:
            stack.append(n + 1)
        elif n == 0:
            stack.extend([m - 1, 1])
        else:
            stack.extend([m - 1, m, n - 1])

    return stack.pop()

print(ackermann(4, 1))
```

This extends the range of arguments we can successfully process, but it soon takes on the order of minutes, or longer, to produce a result.

Comment: That's also an interesting solution. Normally I'd just go with that, but I'm learning about recursion and other techniques which are related to it. Either way, thanks for the response!

Answer (score 1):

The Ackermann function is a recursive function that grows very quickly. When calling `ackermann(4,2)`, the function ends up calling itself recursively `65536` times. The error is because the function ackermann is calling itself recursively too many times.

The maximum recursion depth for Python is 1000, so when you put a value above 3 for m or n, the function will reach the maximum recursion depth and cause an error.

The repeated display of the error message in the console is due to the implementation of memoization in the decorator. Since the function is calling itself recursively, the decorator cannot effectively check if the function has been called before and retrieve the cached result. As a result, the decorator keeps calling the original function, leading to repeated errors and an overflow of error messages.

Answer (score 1):

**An explanation and a fix allowing fast calculation.**

The function grows fast. And its output values are used as the second argument. Consider `ackermann(3, 8)`:

- During its calculation, it calculates `ackermann(2, n)` first up to `n=509`.
- Later it calls `ackermann(2, 1021)`. Which calls `ackermann(2, 1020)`, which calls `ackermann(2, 1019)`, etc, all the way down to the memoized `ackermann(2, 509)`.
- Except it doesn't get that far. From 1021 to 509 is over 500 deep, and your recursion alternates between your actual `ackermann` function and your memoizing wrapper, so it's over 2*500 calls deep. Which exceeds Python's default recursion limit of 1000.
- [Since Python 3.6](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.6.html#traceback), long sequences of repeated lines in tracebacks are abbreviated, which is maybe why you haven't seen that before. But it doesn't abbreviate repeated ***chains*** like the alternation between your actual function and your wrapper.

**A fix:**

Remember the above jump from n=509 to suddenly wanting n=1019. The issue isn't that 1019 is big on its own, the issue is that it is much bigger than the biggest cached case. So let's avoid such large jumps. One way to do that is with a decorator that imposes bottom-up order. For each `m` it remembers the largest cached `n`. So when asked for `n=1019`, it knows that up to `n=509` has already been cached. And then instead of going down from 1019 to 509, it goes **up** from 510 to 1019 **one by one**. While doing that, it ignores the results. They're not the point. The point is to build up the memoization cache.

Here's your code again, but with my `bottom_up` decorator. This computes `ackermann(4, 1)` (which is `ackermann(3, 13)` in less than a second ([Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=hZJNTsMwEIUllj7FLBNoEJFYoIpIvUdVVSadEIt4bDmOKoo4CZtu4FCcBtvNj1si1bvMfH7zXjxfP_rd1oqOx-_OVtnT781hhxVIlEocuFUmqToq0yUDd0pe1ggFfHyGTw_uDdcaTXLLzWvbY_6ICnwFSFkQdLo5dUextYc2TtJP6UVGyqDtDMUgi8r9ZMa8jRdlrZLbTv-zu9vSvGO5AIoMD_B9i9ZhvGusR7J88rOvRYMjuJYbeAY6DxViuGsxdAeRRjwqNAvILwMPIpTO5l2NYdlqeqfwG3j5hkZyojidewoJRQEPy8tB5L2FIjaOonkqEoUM8sUQB5sWr8PnlnwtTRnTRpBNpt6jV01PK9hv4rCRfw)):

```py
def memoizator(func):
    cache = {}
    def wrapper(*args):
        if args not in cache:
            cache[args] = func(*args)
        return cache[args]
    return wrapper

def bottom_up(func):
    cached_n = {}
    def wrapper(m, n):
        cached_n.setdefault(m, -1)
        while cached_n[m] < n:
            func(m, cached_n[m] + 1)
            cached_n[m] += 1
        return func(m, n)
    return wrapper

@bottom_up
@memoizator
def ackermann(m, n):
    if m == 0:
        return n + 1
    elif n == 0:
        return ackermann(m - 1, 1)
    else:
        return ackermann(m - 1, ackermann(m, n - 1))

print(ackermann(4, 1))
```

Comment: Wow, thanks for such a detailed explanation. The solution itself is also pretty smart and impressive, considering how fast this Ackermann function blows up.